# How to serialize HTML without head and body tags using jsdom

Tags: javascript, html, jsdom

I want to clear some tags from a html document like so:

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

function clearAnchorTags(pDom: JSDOM) {
    if (typeof pDom === 'string') {
        pDom = new JSDOM(pDom);
    }

// Get all anchor tags from dom
for (const anchorTag of pDom.window.document.querySelectorAll('a')) {
    for (const child of anchorTag.children) {
        if (child.nodeName === 'EM') {
            const node = pDom.window.document.createTextNode(child.textContent);
            anchorTag.replaceChild(node, child);
        }
        if (child.nodeName === 'B') {
            const node = pDom.window.document.createTextNode(child.textContent);
            anchorTag.replaceChild(node, child);
        }
        if (child.nodeName === 'U') {
            const node = pDom.window.document.createTextNode(child.textContent);
            anchorTag.replaceChild(node, child);
        }
    }
}

// return as string just as we received it -- also replace &nbsp; with space
return pDom.serialize().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
}
```

The issue seems to be the serialize() method here at the end, as it returns a fully featured HTML document.

I need it without the `<html>, <head> and <body>` tags. I only need a HTML fragment.

Comment: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fragment recommends to get the `outerHTML` with fragments. You don't appear to work with an actual fragment here, but I suppose you could still get the outerHTML of `body`, and simply strip off the opening and closing tag from that?

Comment: According to [https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#serializing-the-document-with-serialize](jsdoms README), `serialize()` gives you a full DOM (including DOCTYPE). You probably need to use `pDom.document.getElementById('foo').outerHTML`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem using

```
return pDom.window.document.body.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
```

Comment: works for me, seems like it is the answer

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector("#myElement").outerHTML` allows you to stringify whatever part you want to.

`.serialize` only works against the `dom`.